# Glassfish doesn't create JDBC Resources

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, glassfish

I'm trying to create JDBC Connection Pool and JDBC Resource using glassfish-resources.xml with code below. I've tried to do it with Glassfish 4.0, 4.1, 4.1.1 and Payara. I know there was a problem with 4.1.1, but it **doesnt create to any of them**. I've been trying to solve this problem for several hours, but without a success. PLZ HELP.

```
<resources>
  <jdbc-resource enabled="true"
                 jndi-name="jdbc/affablebean"
                 object-type="user"
                 pool-name="AffableBeanPool">
  </jdbc-resource>

  <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false"
                        associate-with-thread="false"
                        connection-creation-retry-attempts="0"
                        connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10"
                        connection-leak-reclaim="false"
                        connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0"
                        connection-validation-method="auto-commit"
                        datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"
                        fail-all-connections="false"
                        idle-timeout-in-seconds="300"
                        is-connection-validation-required="false"
                        is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true"
                        lazy-connection-association="false"
                        lazy-connection-enlistment="false"
                        match-connections="false"
                        max-connection-usage-count="0"
                        max-pool-size="32"
                        max-wait-time-in-millis="60000"
                        name="AffableBeanPool"
                        non-transactional-connections="false"
                        pool-resize-quantity="2"
                        res-type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource"
                        statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1"
                        steady-pool-size="8"
                        validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0"
                        wrap-jdbc-objects="false">

    <description>Connects to the affablebean database</description>
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/affablebean"/>
    <property name="User" value="root"/>
    <property name="Password" value="nbuser"/>
  </jdbc-connection-pool>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, problem solved... the newest NetBeans 8.1 creates glassfish-resources.xml in the wrong folder. If  you have the same problem, just move your glassfish-resources.xml from Configuration Files to Server Resources...

Comment: Yes this was the fix that helped me. Don't know if its fixed in latest build. But the tutorial should be reflected to be more up to date. I think it still mentions sun-resources.xml.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. the NetBeans tutorial is significantly out of date.